# How do I download, install, and configure VTK 5.0.4 for OSX Maverick 10.9.4?

Tags: cmake, tcl, data-visualization, vtk, paraview

My University course will be using VTK 5.0.4 for Data Visualization. The Professor did not provide any guide on how to install VTK on OSX. Prof says to check the website http://www.vtk.org/VTK/resources/software.html , but I don't see any versions for 5.0.4.

Is it possible to install this version of VTK on Mac Maverick operating system? The textbook to be used is http://www.vtk.org/VTK/help/book.html .

The Prof hinted that the VTK maintainer Kitware probably does not have any VTK binary installation file for OSX Maverick and I may need to install VTK starting from the source code. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seriously doubt 5.0.4 will build on Mavericks. I'd suggest using the latest version instead. You can also use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install the latest VTK.

Comment: The textbook examples are using 5.0.4, would there be any difference with the latest?

Comment: For the most part, you should be fine. Use this to help with the migration, if needed: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_6_Migration_Guide

Answer (score 0):

Probably this helps you to go on

http://www.evl.uic.edu/julian/mac/vtk/

Comment: Thanks. The Xcode used in that guide is very old and I'm having trouble locating Source Tree in Preferences.